# How to show a form with transparency and no border on the task bar in Delphi?

Tags: winforms, forms, delphi, transparency, taskbar

I have a form with a bsNone Bordestyle, with transparency.
To show icon on the Task Bar, I added the following code in the create procedure:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   SetWindowLong(Handle,  GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
end;
```

With this, the icon is displayed but transparency does not work.
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window styles, extended and standard, are **sets** of bit flags. You have set the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` extended style, but cleared all other extended styles. What you meant to do was to use bitwise OR to combine the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` extended style with the existing extended styles.

```
ExStyle := GetWindowLong(Form.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
SetWindowLong(Form.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, ExStyle or WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
```

However, calling `SetWindowLong` is the wrong way to do this. Delphi windows may be re-created and when they are, the styles are re-applied. So the right place for the code is in an overridden `CreateParams` method.

```
procedure TMyForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
end;
```

However, setting `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` is usually the wrong way to put a button onto the taskbar. So long as the window is unowned it will have a button on the taskbar. You can achieve that by setting `MainFormOnTaskbar` to `True`, or by setting `WndParent` to 0 in `CreateParams`.

Comment: Do you understand my point about using `CreateParams`? And do you get what I mean about likely not needing to use `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` at all?